# How can I CRUD with, NHibernate, GridControl, BindingSource

Tags: winforms, nhibernate, devexpress, gridcontrol

I make my first experience with the GridControl und WinForms generally. I bind the data this way:
    ContactBindingSource.DataSource = sess.Query().ToList();
This works fine! But the next step is to insert, edit and delete new records. Which events are important (GridControl and BindingSource) to handle my NHibernate operation.

Comment: You should never bind NHibernate directly to any kind of datasource. Things like lazy loading will soon bite you where it hurts...

Comment: Bind to projections or mapped view model entities

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are binding the grid to BindingSource component.  If so, the best solution for you would be to use its [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged.aspx) event.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

the ListChanged event only fires by new records, or delete record. I can use CurrentItemChanges, but this does not work with the details. And I have a lot details

Comment: I spent more than 4 days for this problem. I need a generally databinding example for this. Included master-details relationship. There is a lot of stuff (Videos etc) but nothing show databinding with nhibernate. I am frustrated!